# Turbo C - stop code re runs

Tags: c

I have a code below where if ran, *scanf* will ask for a *char* type value. As you can see, the code has no for loops or do while, but if a value is inserted the code re runs as long as the value is a *char* type. hope someone could help :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
char name;
clrscr();
printf("welcome who?\n->");
scanf("%s",&name);
getche();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "code re runs"? What exactly do you see happening?

Comment: It's just repeating. It's like i run the code again.

Comment: That's hard to believe. Are you saying the `printf` repeatedly displays?

Comment: How many characters fit in one `char`?

Comment: The %s conversion used by you in the function is not meant for the type char. The type char is just one character. If you want a long string then you need to create an array (either statically or dynamically). (e.g. char name[128])

Comment: @kaylum yes you can try it. this is the first time i have this kind of problem.

Comment: Also, the getche() function prints only one character. My guess would be that if there are more characters in the buffer, you might get some weird behavior. If you want to print the input thats been saved into name then just print it using printf. (As getche() is not even a standard function)

Comment: @Jongware doesnt matter how long

Comment: Bit it *does* matter! A single `char` can only hold **one** character.

Comment: @prkist i saw that %s in youtube tutorial thats why I used it, and %c messes the output.

Comment: @Jongware Im new to Turbo C... I never knew a char could only hold one.  maybe more coding to master this language...

Comment: @Dmitry7715 seems like you should read up **'strings'`** in C. Also additionally some on 'arrays' I guess.

Comment: No one should be "new to Turbo C", any one "new" should not be using it at all.  Get a modern compiler!

Comment: @Clifford no I mean the C language.

Comment: @Dmitry7715 : You have missed my point - Turbo C is a 16 bit MS-DOS compiler the last release of which was in 1988.  If you are new to C, don't start with an antique compiler for an obsolete OS.  Neither the compiler/IDE nor the apps it generates will even run on Win64.  There are modern free toolchains that would be much better choices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You run into **undefined behaviour**. Undefined behaviour means that you're doing something that the you shouldn't and the standard doesn't define, meaning that the compiler is allowed to do anything with your program. That includes working correctly, looping forever, deleting your favorite picture or w/e.

Looking at the name of your variable it seems like you want to read a full 'name' into a single `char` variable, it only has memory for a single letter though.

Change it to something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    char name[51]; // make a char array that's large enough to hold the name
    clrscr();
    printf("welcome who?\n->");
    scanf("%50s",&name); // read a string of up to 50 characters.
    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that we need to have 1 more space than what we read for the '\0' character at a string, meaning that your original code couldn't read even a single character.

Also as a general personal advice, please don't use Turbo C/C++ unless you're absolutely forced to by a professor, they are completely outdated.

Comment: so that is what I am missing. C is much complicated than I thought.